# Partial match vlookup in a sentence

Tags: google-sheets, gs-vlookup

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16NqKD4OGVAwwVK38dht1_NbFrMxkSSIeTXvxOcYXCRg/edit?usp=sharing

Do you do a partial `vlookup`, searching for a word in a sentence? I have downloaded my bank statement CSV and the description of the payment is quite long-winded, I am looking to categorize each payment. In this example, I am looking to categorize 'Waitrose' as a 'Grocery' purchase.

Please feel free to try formula and make edits to the sheet, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(REGEXEXTRACT(C2:C, 
 TEXTJOIN("|", 1, Category!D2:D)), Category!D2:F, {1, 2, 3}, 0)))
```

[image: 0]